# Pre render Blade template & return result in AJAX

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Is there a way I can render Blade template & return result in AJAX ?

I have a custom template, where the first few items are loaded on page load. The remaining items are loaded via ajax. Can I use a template file to return the rendered layout via ajax ?

Answer (score 4):

```
// Controller method
public function ajaxMethod()
{
    $data = [
        'view' => View::make('path/to/the/view')
            ->with('userLetsSay', $userData)
            ->render()
    ];

    return Response::json($data, 200);
}

// AJAX callback on success.
// ...

success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.view);
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like this ([Check this article](http://heera.it/laravel-view-rendersections#.U4OP1vmSySo)):

```
$view = View::make('home.index')->with('something', $something);
return $view->renderSections()['content']; // Get rendered @section('content')
```

Also you may exclude the template for an `ajax` call and return the raw data to client side and then insert that data into `DOM` using `JavaScript` but not sure how you are doing it so can't be more specific.

**Update:** You may also render the full template and can send it to client side (other answer provided it).